Liquid simulation in small scale
I need to create water simulation in the scale of a Glass cup (domain = 10 cm)
When I run simulation in the Blenders default domain size (1m) it all goes nice, but when preparing the same simulation much smaller, the color spheres are too large, and simulation goes wrong.
Do you know where is the magic parameter to change the scale?


When you simulate a fluid, the Domain has a Particle System for the fluid particles. The Size of these particles you can change in the Particle System Properties under Viewport Display. The Size there is always in absolute dimensions, independent from the Domain's scale.

However I have to disappoint you: this is just the size they are displayed with, changing it will not change anything in your simulation.
The only thing that will make the simulation better is probably the Resolution Divisions of the Domain, because this is the "real" size of the fluid particles or voxels. The higher the resolution, the smaller the particles. The smaller they are, the less errors Blender makes in calculating if something is inside or outside of an Effector object.

But even then it might still not work, because the glass is probably too thin for quickly moving particles to "catch" them in the right moment before they went where they should not go. To help with that, you could increase the Sampling Substeps on either the Flow object, the Effector or both. I build a similar scene like you, but with 50 substeps it still was not perfect.

Or you could make the glass ridiculously thick, then there is less to no chance that fluid particles will make it to the outside. This thick glass you would use only for simulating, for rendering you would place a normal glass in the scene. But this would make problems if you want the liquid to flow over the brim of the glass of course.
And be aware, all of these settings can drastically increase the simulation baking time. In general you could say, the simulation works better with larger objects, so unfortunately simulating in (small) real-life sizes can be very frustrating.

Could you bake first and scale later?

@DanielMöller Yes, this would actually work. Although theoretically the simulations take dimensions into acount, i.e. a body of water filling up a tank with a volume of a cubic meter would be different then filling up a can with a volume of 1 liter. But since the simulation's behaviour is also dependent on the domain's Resolution Divisions you might get away with it. Just like in Hollywood a flood might be made with a smaller scale model - but there comes a point where you can see that the waves and splashes have a different size than they should actually have and it looks unrealistic.

@DanielMöller Oh, and not to forget, the dimensions taken into account are also gravity settings. If you scale something to a size of 1 m for simulation and scale it down to 10 cm later, a drop of water falling down 10 cm will take the time it needs to fall down 1 m. Sure you can compensate things like that with speed settings or changing the gravity, but it will not be the same as the real-life dimensions.
